# What is meaning of $g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo 2>&1

Tags: c++

I want to know what is meaning of the following statement in Unix -

```
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo 2>&1
```

Comment: what part or parts have you confused?

Comment: sounds like you want a magic homework-solving crystal ball

Comment: You could start with `man g++`.

Answer (score 3):

Call the GNU C++ compiler:

```
g++
```

Set the language standard to C++11:

```
-std=c++11
```

The input source file is `main.cpp`:

```
main.cpp
```

Set the output (`-o`) filename to `demo`:

```
-o demo
```

Redirect (the `>` character) standard error (represented by `2`) to standard output (represented by `1`):

```
2>&1
```

Both standard error and the standard output are linked to the console screen already by default.

Comment: Thanks... Helped a lot